# E:The package picasa:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

Tired of getting this error again and again and it's blocking ubuntu software center from getting started it's just crashing when I try to open it.
And getting this error at the time of installing and updating software center and any other application.
It's blocking the installation.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is trying to reinstall or update the `picasa:i386` package, but the system does not find the corresponding `.deb` file. The `apt` and `apt-get` commands try to obtain the packages from PPA repositories. If you installed picasa (or another software) (1) downloading a `.deb` instead of using these repositories or (2) using a dead repository, you may end with packages you cannot update.

**If you need Picasa**, you may try to [find the software you used to install it](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-install-picasa-36-in-ubuntu.html).

- I tried to install the Picasa by adding the old *testing* repository of Google. However, I got an `W: Unable to download ...` error after configuring the testing repository that included Picasa.

  ```
  # it does not work !!
  $ sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ testing non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list"
  $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7FAC5991 
  $ sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Apparently, the [installation process](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-install-picasa-36-in-ubuntu.html) uses Wine and the windows version of Picasa. You may try to [download Picasa from other non-google sites](https://picasa.uptodown.com/windows).

**If you do not need Picasa**. I think you must uninstall the (unsupported) picasa.

```
    $ sudo apt-get remove picasa
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---